# Import package from upper level of application

Tags: python, import, importerror

So I have an application with a structure of:

```
main.py
core/__init__.py
core/user_interface.py
core/util/__init__.py
core/util/widgets/__init__.py
core/util/widgets/tab.py
```

The main.py file makes an import of:

```
from core import user_interface
```

This runs successfully, then user_interface makes an import call:

```
import core.util.widgets.tab
```

The file tab.py then has an import call:

```
from core import user_interface
```

This last import fails and returns the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name user_interface
```

Execution of the application or attempts to import the user_interface module from the terminal fail with this error since the chain of imports is breaking. I know I'm making a very basic mistake somewhere, but I am about at my wit's end with this thing. If anyone can help resolve this I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced the exact same problem - but it only appears if the module is called `core`. (I proved this by renaming the module and it worked fine. Renaming back to `core` and the `ImportError` exception is thrown again).

I'm fairly new to python but have concluded it's due to another module called `core` already existing on my Python path (although I can't find one).

I solved this by simply choosing a different name for my module (or rather Django app)

Answer (score 0):

This is a circular import. You are doing `import core.util.widgets.tab` from `user_interface` and then trying to import `user_interface` from within `tab`. It's an import which can never be completed do to the nature of each depending on the other. This article talks about them in more detail: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports.

Comment: My mistake, brain glitch from hand-typing. ui is user_interface. I'll edit the above.

Comment: the full import line in tab.py is:

    from core import ui, host, events, language, paths

Which results in this error:

    File "/home/james/Documents/Projects/SCD/core/scd/widget/tab.py", line 10, in <module>  
    from core import user_interface, host, events, language, paths  
    ImportError: cannot import name user_interface

Comment: Is there a way to allow tab.py to access components of user_interface.py then? I am hacking on re-purposing some code, and though a lot of the actual code has changed, the import order like that is the same as it was in the original application for those two files. *Edits for same mistake....*

Comment: Well, apparently I need to refactor more then. Wonder why on earth the original code worked at all then.

Comment: Might be easiest to move the code `tab` requires out of `user_interface` and into another module they can both import from.